# ¿Cómo resolver esta integral con exponenciales negativas?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, python-2.x

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O73Ds.png]

Intente agregar lo siguiente:
from sympy.abc import x, i
f=lambda y, t: (exp(-1*x))*(exp(-1*y))
f
f(0,0)
Pero el error es el mismo

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás mezclando la sintaxis muy propia de Sympy con la de Numpy y Math. Ni Numpy ni Math trabajan con símbolos por lo que al colocar `math.exp(expr)` intentará resolver numéricamente la expresión, mostrando el error que ves.

La solución es darle una leída al módulo [Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/reference/index.html) y usar la [sintaxis adecuada](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html#sympy.integrals.integrals.integrate) para declarar la ecuación.

```py
from sympy import exp, I, integrate, oo
from sympy.abc import x, y

f = (exp(-I*x))*(exp(-I*y))
fr = integrate(f, (y, 0, oo))
print(fr)
```

Ni idea si es el resultado que buscas, pero ya sabes la causa del fallo.